# Woocommerce - the number of the selected product appears in all forms of other products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product, cart

Good evening.
Please help me!

I have a website and moved from cards products form the number of and variations in the category. I did it using code, which is placed in the theme file functions.php:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 10);
```

However, when I select 2 or more number of same product and click "add to cart",  the number of the selected product appears in all forms of other products.

Here is screenshot and a link to my test site:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyBKk.jpg)

http://xarod.tk/shop/

I also put code:

```
<div class="abe"><?woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart(); ?></div>
```

in the file woocommerce/templates/content-product.php, but got the same thing.